# How to subtract to excel Date and time Now() functions

Tags: excel, vba

Im looking at creating a ticketing system in excel, where double clicking a cell at the beginning of the ticket generates a date and time with the now() function, and then double clicking another cell at the end of the ticket does the same. I have done this with code already I found online.

However my goal is to subtract these two values to get a "ticket duration" amount however the nature of the now() function also includes the date so there is no simple a1-b1 function I can do in excel that works as the date gives the function an error. I simply want to subtract the two times generated, not the dates.

Any ideas on how to work around this?

Edit:
Example how the cells look:
1/18/2018  3:51:37 PM   1/18/2018  3:53:47 PM

Comment: why do you think the date has anything to do with your unexplained problem?

Comment: Because I assume excel cant subtract dates& times from eachother. Maybe by themselves yes but not coupled together

Comment: 1/18/2018  3:51:37 PM 1/18/2018  3:53:47 PM
Example of how the cells look.

Comment: you wrote a1-b1 doesn't work. maybe try b1-a1 and format as [hh]:mm:ss

Comment: You have to understand that dates/times are just numbers.  (My current date/time is represented as the number `43118.7634854167`.)  You can subtract them like any other numbers.  It's only when you format them with a date format that they **display** as a date (but they are still just numbers).